# Why overload true and false instead of defining bool operator?

Tags: c#, boolean, overloading, operator-keyword

I've been reading about overloading true and false in C#, and I think I understand the basic difference between this and defining a bool operator.  The example I see around is something like:

```
public static bool operator true(Foo foo) {
  return (foo.PropA > 0);
}
public static bool operator false(Foo foo) {
  return (foo.PropA <= 0);
}
```

To me, this is the same as saying:

```
public static implicit operator bool(Foo foo) {
  return (foo.PropA > 0);
}
```

The difference, as far as I can tell, is that by defining true and false separately, you can have an object that is both true and false, or neither true nor false:

```
public static bool operator true(Foo foo) { return true; }
public static bool operator false(Foo foo) { return true; }
//or
public static bool operator true(Foo foo) { return false; }
public static bool operator false(Foo foo) { return false; }
```

I'm sure there's a reason this is allowed, but I just can't think of what it is.  To me, if you want an object to be able to be converted to true or false, a single bool operator makes the most sense.

Can anyone give me a scenario where it makes sense to do it the other way?

Thanks

Comment: I've just found these operators as well and did some tests. It seems like `if` only uses the `true` operator, and `if (!myObj)` is not possible at all, so there's no point (yet) in implementing a contradictory `false` operator. Did I miss anything? How can I use the `false` operator at all?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahhcxk2(VS.71).aspx#vclrftrueanchor_trueoperator) say, overloading `true` and `false` is intended to support (nullable) database-types (Yes/No, Y/N, 0/1, etc).

And of course you can define them inconsistently, as with any operator. It is your responsibility to return something sensible. The compiler goes no further than requiring neither or both.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't get that far in MSDN - I started looking elsewhere after their [operator overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467(VS.71%29.aspx "operator overloading") page, which wasn't much help.  I suppose I didn't think about the fact that you can overload ==/!= the same way, where they conflict with each other, I just could never imagine actually doing it.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 8):

I had no idea these operators existed.  That means you can implement the self-negation paradox:

```
public class ThisClassIsFalse
{
    public static bool operator true(ThisClassIsFalse statement)
    {
        return statement ? false : true;
    }

    public static bool operator false(ThisClassIsFalse statement)
    {
        return statement ? true : false;
    }
}
```

So now we know the true solution to this classic paradox... StackOverflowException.

Comment: public bool ThisMethodReturnsFalse() { return true; }

Answer (score 2):

I've seen people overload the `true` and `false` overloads in order to do clever things like building expressions in .NET 2.0, before Linq existed.

[Ayende](http://www.ayende.com/) worked out a syntax like this to build NHibernate criteria queries, using his NHQG project:

```
return Repository.FindAll(
    (Where.Publisher.Name == name) &&
    (Where.Publisher.City == city));
```

Comment: Ahh, the days before LINQ...Those were innocent times when people did atrocious things that were clever at the time...

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the system, true can be any non-zero value.  In others, it can be any positive value.

Other systems aren't truly boolean, and allow a third state null or nill for the boolean values, which is why you might overload true and false, versus overloading a single bool operator.

Comment: This is specifically for .NET, so are you saying that it's for .NET applications talking to non-.NET code?

Comment: Joe, this is a feature in the specification for C#, not .NET.  C# could be used in any system, and true and false might need their definition changed.

Comment: Benjamin: Thanks for the response - a few comments:

First, I believe this is the case for other .NET languages, not just C# - VB.NET has special operators IsTrue and IsFalse which seem to be the same thing, unless I'm mistaken.

Also, you mentioned that C# could be used in any system - I've heard a few people say things like this in the past, but I've never heard explanations.  Other than Mono, is there any other place outside of .NET where C# is actually used?

Thanks

Comment: Mono is the primary alternative implementation of C#, but C# the language is an open ISO standard, and can be used and implemented by anyone that wants to do the work to implement it.